# SQL select values based on other two columns

Tags: sql, select

If I have a table like:

| Name | Subject | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | Math | 90 |
| Tom | Physics | 70 |
| Jerry | Math | 70 |
| Jerry | Physics | 90 |
| Bob | Math | 80 |
| Bob | Physics | 80 |

How to write SQL code to find the names who do better at math rather than physics?

The output should be:

| Name |
| --- |
| Tom |

Comment: You should. edit your question and show what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd join two queries on the table, one for math and one for physics:

```sql
SELECT m.name
FROM   (SELECT name, score
        FROM   mytable
        WHERE  subject = 'Math') m
JOIN   (SELECT name, score
        FROM   mytable
        WHERE  subject = 'Physics') p ON m.name = p.name AND m.score > p.score
```

Answer (score 1):

Many ways. One way is to say you want to know which names have maths who also have subject physics that exists with a lower score, so

```
select *
from t
where subject='maths' and exists (
  select * from t t2 where t2.name=t.name 
    and t2.subject='physics'
    and t2.score < t.score
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check my solution in [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vDEb9MphJfm752ExoreMHz/0) with data.

In short, You can apply below query

```
SELECT 
      s1.Name
      FROM TableName s1, TableName s2
WHERE s1.Name = s2.Name 
AND s1.Subject = 'Math' AND s2.Subject = 'Physics' 
AND s1.Score > s2.Score
```